# organize python project in Eclipse in packages

Tags: python, eclipse

I have an eclipse python project. 
In this project i had a package called PX. Now i have created 2 new packages PXTest and PXProd for different development "stages". When i develope something in PX, I copy the modified source to PXTest and when it's working, I copy it to PXProd:[image]

I have a problem now:

all the imports reference the package name and I would need to replace them everytime I copy sources. like:

> from PX.functions import send_email

is there a way to reference the import within the package automatically? since the package structure is the same, I hope to find a way to use relative paths or something like that.

any suggestions?

thanks and best wishes, E.

Comment: or can I assign 'PX' to a variable and then import from the Var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after googling i found out, that there are relative paths in python/eclipse. but i prefered creating 3 separate projects with the same package name. thanks!